# Want to extract value from regular expression extractor

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, run one API and get the below response. I want to extract File_Name & ReqId value from the below response using Regular Expression Extractor. Here we want to use only one "Regular Expression Extractor", & extract these 2 values and pass these two values to another API, so how do that?

{"FileCode":["Aadhar"],"File_Name":"271954143_1_1.jpg","Aadhar_Features":[{"Confidence":"79.46","File_Code":"UIA","Count":1},{"Confidence":"87.87","File_Code":"GOI","Count":1},{"Confidence":"88.25","File_Code":"Aadhar_Slogan","Count":1},{"Confidence":"92.36","File_Code":"SatyamevaJayateLogo","Count":1},{"Confidence":"92.99","File_Code":"AadharLogo","Count":1},{"Confidence":"97.01","File_Code":"Aadhar","Count":2}],"ReqId":"REQ_1639032634869","Classes":[{"Confidence":[96.21741771697998,98.64940047264099],"Coordinates":["383,269,110.0,27","375,882,105.33333333333333,28"],"Count":2,"Name":"AadharNo"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Because your response object is JSON, it is recommended to use JSON Extractor.

[image]

Observe the output variables in debug controller

[image]